# Detect deleted questions with many upvotes

Tags: support, deleted-questions, bookmarks

Recently I have bookmarked a classic question (**+128** upvotes) that after a couple of weeks has mysteriously disappeared because deleted.
I have to say thanks to my bookmark that allowed me to track it down<sup>*</sup>, anyway it was just a lucky coincidence.

Do you guys have some way to detect deleted questions with a great number of votes in your awesome backoffice tools<sup>**</sup>?
With millions of questions to handle, I think it is possible to make some mistakes that could lead to losing sweet and neat answers silently.

<sup>* After the proper request, the deleted question was kindly undeleted</sup>
<sup>** I'm aware of the Locked Status (apparently it was not enough to prevent the question's deletion)</sup>

Comment: Am I the only one what's curious what the particular classic question was?

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1707/terminal-tips-and-tricks-for-mac-os-x-is-missing @dra

Comment: See related `feature-request`: [Show votes on recently deleted posts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71346/show-votes-on-recently-deleted-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mods (and 10k users) have list of *all* recently deleted posts, that we peruse.
Mods of course can undelete, and 10k users can vote to undelete.

Currently we can't immediately see the number of votes on each, but I've created a [feature request for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71346/show-votes-on-recently-deleted-posts).

Comment: was your request onored?

Comment: @systempunttoout Not yet, but it's not `[status-declined]` either.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it yourself via the monthly data dumps.  Import two months to compare to the database of your choice and write a query that first filters the older dump for questions with votes >= 100 and joins the results to the new dump with either left join where the right side is null or using a not exists directive.

Comment: @Joel thanks, is it not possible using Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Comment: @systempuntoout No, it is not, because you need copies from two different months loaded into a database at the same time.

Comment: @Joel Are you saying that because with Data Explorer we can't query deleted answers?

Comment: That is correct.  Deleted posts are not exported in the monthly data dumps used for the explorer.  The only way to detect them is to find posts that were in one dump and not in another, and even then you'll miss many that never made it to a data dump in the first place.

Comment: @Joel yep, that's why I'm asking it; I think you can do it with a single query against the datastore, isn't it?

Comment: @system - you can do it with a single query, but only if you've loaded a datastore from two different months to your database.

Comment: @Joel sorry, I'm talking about the sysadmins or mods, if you have access to the real datastore (not the data dumps)

Comment: @system Mods (and 10k users) have list of *all* recently deleted posts, that we peruse.  We can't immediately see the upvotes.  I'll request that as a new feature.