# Show votes on recently deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

After reading *[Detect deleted questions with many upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71198/detect-deleted-questions-with-many-upvotes)* I reviewed the 10k tools for deleted posts.

Unfortunately, you cannot tell what the voting was on a post without clicking on it.  It would be useful to be able to see at a glance the votes, and perhaps views on a question, of a post that was deleted.  It would also be helpful to style posts with a certain threshold of votes differently, to indicate they are likely worth keeping.

**tl;dr**: Please show a post's votes on the `recently deleted posts` tool and style posts with many upvotes differently.

Comment: Good suggestion - handy that I'm in that area at the moment.

Comment: If we really need a TL;DR for 4 sentences, then I fear for the world. ;)

Comment: @Onion-Knight: TL;DR: We in bad shape.