# rep threshold to delete a question; close versus delete

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, deleted-questions

It is ***very*** frustrating when a question gets deleted, especially in the middle of trying to help someone. This has happened at least twice to me now, where someone (usually with lower rep, and, granted, sometimes a lower quality question) responds with a comment, edit, vote, etc. and I get notified about it in my inbox (the header/ribbon at the top of the SE pages). I then click on the update and land at a `404`. I have been suspicious at least one of these was a user who deleted their own post.

Is there a rep threshold for deletion of one's own question? More importantly, **should there be and how high?** Otherwise, *what is a viable workaround to still see the post, if possible?* Should lower rep users only be able to close their question until the community or others vote/approve to delete?

Possibly related:

- [Deleted Meta Questions Archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-meta-questions-archive)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
- [Notification for when Community is about to delete a Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247958/notification-for-when-community-is-about-to-delete-a-question)
- [Automatic deletion of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92393/automatic-deletion-of-a-question)

Basically this sort of thing is a real drag and leaves the experience wanting because a lot of times in trying to help (typ. via comments) I can be learning something, too. Then it all goes away... forever...

On any SE site, I'm currently a long ways from reaching the 10k point, which looks like it may offer some recourse for this issue: [Show votes on recently deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71346/show-votes-on-recently-deleted-posts).

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm asking a researched question which specifies the details of my question. What I was able to find (linked in the OP) wasn't satisfactory in answering these details. I'm also attempting to learn by asking in order to discover the perspective behind the answers for these details.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a rep threshold for deletion of one's own question?

No. You can delete your question if it doesn't have any positively scored answers.

> More importantly, **should there be and how high?**

No. Something that might be useful is a time that the question can't be self-deleted after it has received an answer. This prevents users from deleting their post immediately after receiving an answer and will give other users the chance to vote on the answer.

> Otherwise, what is a viable workaround to still see the post, if possible?

Acquire 10K reputation. Then you can see deleted posts.

> Should lower rep users only be able to close their question until the community or others vote/approve to delete?

No. The solution mentioned earlier will prevent malicious deletions. That is enough.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for the answer. How exactly are you defining "malicious deletions"? I've observed some questions have quite a lot of comments prior to receiving an answer (for various and good reasons). What would the argument be against extending the "can't delete with answer" to "can't delete with answer *or comment*"?

Comment: Comments: no. They don't hurt when deleted. They can be deleted by a moderator at any time for no specific reason. If a user puts effort in a full explaining answer, and an user instantly deletes the question, that is deletion with bad intentions.