# Question about Recalculation of Reputation

Tags: support, reputation, questions, reputation-recalc

Hello I triggered recalc using

```
http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?recalc=true
```

But after 5 min my reputation from `11928`  became `11865` Why ?

How can I trace out  the problem ?

Comment: Um... what problem?

Comment: Don't forget, "reputation can down as well as up".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What problem? The system did exactly what you asked it to do.

Your displayed reputation is denormalized from your posts, and as posts get deleted (or undeleted), the actual rep and displayed rep gets out of sync. A reputation recalc synchronizes the two.

Comment: if I don't hit then when system recalc it self ?

Comment: @org: By default, never. That being said, moderators are able to trigger a recalc on your account at any time.

Comment: Thanks, If I want to traceout the info about deduction how can I ?

Comment: @org: Unfortunately, that's not directly possible because the system views deleted posts as if they never existed. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71198/detect-deleted-questions-with-many-upvotes) for a possible way to find these posts.